# Script to cleanup duplicate files based on filesize

Tags: perl, vbscript, wsh

I've got some backup log files on a Windows XP machine stores as follows:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
4.txt
5.txt
```

All of them have the files from 1-3  have same filesize and 2-5 have same filesize . I want to store one of them from each set having same filesize and delete the rest. Can someone suggest a script to do that?

Comment: If you have a lot of files, comparing by size for equality may not be a good idea. You have to be careful of the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Comment: I've got a million files of log with sequentially updated numbered timestamps, but same filesizes for some. What is a good way to maintain only one copy of each logfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The worked example from [File::Find::Duplicates](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aDuplicates) (slightly adapted) is probably a good start:

```
use File::Find::Duplicates;

my @dupes = find_duplicate_files('/tmp/dup');

foreach my $dupeset (@dupes) { 
    printf "Files %s (of size %d) hash to %s\n",
    join(", ", @{$dupeset->files}), $dupeset->size, $dupeset->md5;
}
```

[File::Find::Duplicates](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aFind%3a%3aDuplicates) matches on size and MD5 checksum, which is probably what you want.